# How to find if List values ​are in ascending order, fixed number between two values

Tags: java, list, sorting

Suppose I hold lists whose members have Integer values ​​as follows

```
List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<>();
li.add(1);
li.add(2);
li.add(3);
li.add(4);
li.add(5);


List<Integer> li1 = new ArrayList<>();
li1.add(3);
li1.add(5);
li1.add(6);
li1.add(7);
li1.add(8);
li1.add(9);
```

I want to find out if the lists are sorted in ascending order, **but with a fixed difference value between any two members, say 1**. (You can think of a kind of Arithmetic progression whose 'd' is 1)

The naive solution proposed is to loop through all the members of the list and check each element[i + 1], whether when the element[i] is subtracted from it, whether 1 is obtained, as follows

```
public static boolean checkSequenceList(List<Integer> li){
    for (int i = 0; i < li.size() - 1; i++) {
        if (li.get(i+1) - li.get(i) != 1)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Is there a more effective way / abbreviated writing style to do this?

Comment: There is no more effective way than to check each element once. Your code above won't work for `d != 1`, however.

Comment: @Kon u right. But then again, I can change ' li.get(i+1) - li.get(i) != p', while the function's signature is 'public static boolean checkSequenceList(List<Integer> li, int p)'.
That way u can fit it to every Arithmetic progression formula. 
And thanks for the response. I would wait to hear more reviews, especially regarding an alternative code style.

Comment: You have to check each element, but only for as long as the atithmetic progression holds. Once you found an incorrect value, you can break the loop.

Answer (score 0):

How about you all the values in an Array and then sorting the array by using `Array.Sort(arrayname)`, then they should be put in ascending order automatically. If you just want to check it you can compare the array with the sorted array.

Answer (score 0):

An approach could be to use IntStream. If you use the indices and the values as x and y values of a mathematical function, like below:

```
x (index)    y (list.get(x))  

0            4
1            5
2            6
3            7
4            8
5            9
```

your requierment (that they should be sorted and have same difference) implies that they should satisfy a linear function `y = mx + b` where `b` is the first value in list at index `0` and  `m` being the delta. So you could do something like:

```
public static boolean checkSequenceList(List<Integer> li, int m){
    return IntStream.range(0, li.size()).allMatch(x -> m*x + li.get(0) == li.get(x));
}
```

You can ommit `m` if the delta you care about is always `1`

```
public static boolean checkSequenceList(List<Integer> li){
    return IntStream.range(0, li.size()).allMatch(x -> x + li.get(0) == li.get(x));
}
```

and it will also short-circuit since [allMatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) is a short-circuiting terminal operation, i.e. you will not iterate over the whole list if a mismatch is found.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean checkSequenceList(List<Integer> integerList, int d) {
    int lastNum = integerList.get(0);

    for (int i = 1; i < integerList.size(); i++) {
        Integer integer = integerList.get(i);
        if (integer - lastNum != d) {
            return false;
        }
        lastNum = integer;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code with any difference between consequence items.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
        values.add(3);
        values.add(4);
        values.add(5);
        values.add(6);
        values.add(8);
        values.add(9);

        pairwiseDifference(values);
    }

    static void pairwiseDifference(List<Integer> values) {
        int diff = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < values.size() - 1; i++) {
            int curDiff = values.get(i + 1) - values.get(i);

            if (i == 0)
                diff = curDiff;
            else if (diff != curDiff) {
                System.out.println("Items " + values.get(i) + " and "+values.get(i+1) + " have not same difference as previous pair");
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Items have same difference");
    }
}
```